# Use Shared Code For 501 Programming Assignment Exam

Tags: code

The new programming assignment is coming,
can i use official shared code to complete the task?

like:

developer.force.com/codeshare

or [Smart Factory](http://developer.force.com/projectpage?id=a063000000Db0CSAAZ)

or Apex Enterprise Patterns

or Flow Factory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you don't use shared code. The assignment is probably going to be specific enough that you'll find shared code to not be a great fit, and then you'd probably get docked for unnecessary implementation. This is a good opportunity for you to implement something from scratch to prove that you can. I'm also going to go out on a limb and say using "other people's code" is probably against the rules.

Answer (score 2):

Although i am not an examiner of 501 programming assignment or infact no where  related to salesforce certification team but I strongly feel these should be totally fine and these are best practices ,so hence feel should do no harm but again a big disclaimer that you would like to be clarified this with certification team by dropping a case .